# is there a way to populate an array inside an object inside an array of objects in mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

So, I have 3 schemas,

User

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...,    
    weekly: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Weekly'
    }]
});
```

Weekly

```
const weeklyAnalyticSchema = new mongoose.Schema({      
  daily: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'DailyAnalytic'
  }],
  weekStart: {
    type: Date,
    // default: addDaystoDate(1)
  },
  weekEnd: {
    type: Date,
    // default: addDaystoDate(7)
  }
})
```

Daily

```
const Daily = new mongoose.Schema({
  date: Date,
  foo: bar
})
```

I'm trying to populate the daily array inside the weekly array,
like so...

I do this, following the documentation from mongoosejs [mongoose deep populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate)

```
let found = await db.User.findById(req.user._id).populate({
path: "weeklyAnalytics",
populate: {
  path: "dailyAnalytics"
}).exec()
```

and it comes out like this

```
 daily: [ 1],
  weekly: [
    {
      daily: [Array],
      _id: 1,                   
      __v: 0
    }
  ],
```

i've tried many others as well and read and modified other peoples code, but I can't seem to get that daily inside the weekly to populate.

Answer (score 1):

why does the answer always come up to the questioner after he asks the question

i just have to do `console.log(found.week)` and everything will show up.

now I can do whatever.